# How to add an external file as library to browserify/gulp

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp, browserify

I have the following project structure:

```
+ lib
   lib1.js
   lib2.js
+ app
   node_modules/...
   file1.js
   file2.js
   Gulpfile.js
   package.json
```

Now I would like to write `file1.js`:

```
var x = require('lib1');
var y = require('lib2');
```

and have browserify 'link' the files correctly.

This is what I've tried:

```
gulp.task('js', function () {
    var b = browserify(['./file1.js'], {
        debug: true,
        "require": ["react", "jquery", "../lib/lib1.js:lib1", "../lib/lib2.js:lib2"]
    });

    return b.bundle()
    // ...
});
```

(analog to https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#external-requires , which suggest `-r ./my-file.js:my-module` for the command line.)

That results in:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/me/test/lib/lib1.js:lib1' from '/Users/me/test/app'
```